# Argsort returns negative values in reverse order

Tags: python, arrays, sorting

So I have an 2d array where the first column consists of floats ranging between `-1.0` and `1.0`. I want to sort the array based on the first column, from lowest to highest, this way:

```
data[0,data[0,:].argsort()]
```

But the problem is that the negative values are sorted from highest to lowest value, so `-0.26` comes before `-0.56`,  while the positive values are sorted from lowest to highest, `0.26` before `0.56` for example.

Why is this happening and how can I get the correct results, that is that also the negative values are listed from lowest to largest value?

Comment: the first column of `data` is `data[:, 0]`, not `data[0, :]`.

Comment: Sorry, I meant row, not column. Doesn't affect the problem

Comment: what is the dtype of your array?

Comment: It is `numpy.ndarray`

Comment: I means the dtype, you can get it by `data.dtype`.

Comment: I get the answer `|S32`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your array is a string array, so you need to convert it to float array first:

```
data = data.astype(float)
data[0,data[0,:].argsort()]
```

Comment: Ah such a simple solution to a stupid problem. Thank you, I forgot that the whole array only has one type!

Comment: In my case the reason was different integer types (int64 vs int16)